# Aiohttp routing (aiohttp.web.RouteTableDef)

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have a problems with RouteTableDef.
There is some project where routing structure like this:

1) There is file `route.py`.
    routes.py

```
from aiohttp import web
routes = web.RouteTableDef()
```

2) There are some handlers in different files, for example:
handler1.py

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import routes

@routes.get('/get')
async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)
```

and so on.
3) and main file, where app runs:

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_routes(routes)

    web.run_app(app, host='localhost', port=8877)
```

The idea is:
all routes store at `routes` variable, when we wanna create new handler we import that variable from `routes.py` and use it.
In order to register routes to app, we import `routes` from `routes.py`.
And how to make it working with aiohttp v3.3.2?

The problem is: it works with aiohttp version 2.3.10.
But there is the real project with this way of routing and it works.
How to create a one place that will store routes?
I suppose that problem is in lib version, because that project doesn't work with the latest version of aiohttp.

Comment: Check `routes` content before `app.router.add_routes()` call.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Here is also some interesting thing. If i check `routes`  variable in existing project, that variable has all routes that have to be. But when i create project from scratch (like above) `routes` is empty. I did it all the same way as at that project but `routes` is empty.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I've solved the problem. I need to import request handler to file, where i create and run web.Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import request handler `handle` to file where `web.Application` creates and runs. Import it before importing `routes` from `routes.py`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is order of the imports, as already answered. This is one of the reasons why I create one `web.RouteTableDef()` in each file and then I put them together for `app.router`:

```py
from .dashboard import routes as dashboard_routes
from .posts import routes as posts_routes

app.router.add_routes([
    *dashboard_routes,
    *posts_routes,
])
```